# TinyMCE strips inline style with valid-elements: *[*] with Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, attributes, tinymce, strip-tags

I have read [Tinymce strips attributes on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190542/tinymce-strips-attributes-on-submit),  [TinyMce Allow all Html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266487/tinymce-allow-all-html-tag), [TinyMCE valid elements: only allow specific CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165586/tinymce-valid-elements-only-allow-specific-css-rules), [how to prevent tinymce from stripping the 'style' attribute from input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290121/how-to-prevent-tinymce-from-stripping-the-style-attribute-from-input-element), [TinyMCE, allow data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744903/tinymce-allow-data-attribute) and many others...

But none of them work.

This is my code:

```
valid_elements : '+*[*]',
cleanup: false,
inline_styles : true
```

I have also tried

```
valid_elements : '*[*]'
```

(without `+` before `*[*]`)

and even

```
valid_children : '+body[style]'
```

But when I add the styles manually like `style="color: #fff;"` and submit the form, TinyMCE removes the returned output.

**In other words: I want TinyMCE to stop 'removing' any code automatically.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **No**, it was not TinyMCE that was preventing inline styles.

## **CodeIgniter** did that.

Even now that I had manually disabled XSS filtering using:

```
$body = $this->input('body', FALSE);
```

, that was still being removed **because I had enabled XSS filtering in `application/config/config.php`**:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

---

But when I changed it to

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

the problem was resolved and I got rid of the Server Side filtering.

---

I post the answer here and I hope no one else be such crazy and mad that I became!

Comment: You have no idea how much I love you for posting this! I just spent six hours working with this to try and figure it out and was just about to ask a question. So thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Very happy to see it is helping you `:)`

Comment: Awesome! I spent countless hours scouring the Internet and TinyMCE posts everywhere to figure this out! One extra thing I had to do was to remove `xss_clean` from my validation rules as well!